# Can a compromised OpenSSHD server be used to upload a malicious payload to a client?

Tags: malware, ssh, protocols, opensource

Since I'm fairly unfamiliar with the specific details of the SSH protocol, I was wondering if it was possible for a compromised SSHd server to upload a malicious payload (like a Trojan or some other nefarious code) back to a completely uncompromised client who was connecting to it.

I suppose a poorly-coded SSH client could definitely fall victim to this kind of attack through some sort of buffer overflow, but could it happen to a SSH client that followed the protocol to the letter, like the well-maintained, stable, and battle-tested like the OpenSSH client?  If so, has a documented example of such an exploit occurred in the past?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The server is sending back data of its choice to be processed by the client. If there is a flaw or an exploit, it can be taken advantage of by the malicious server. Even if this is legitimate software.

The fact that its well maintained, battle tested, etc does not mean its guaranteed to be free of vulnerabilities. There may be new bugs introduced with new features, protocol misimplementations, etc. The probability may be lower, but its not impossible.

---

Based on your edit as we discussed below, the protocol does not need to have a flaw in order to be abused. Following the protocol does not mean it's not use weak ciphers, misimplementations in processing, etc. It can follow the protocol and bad things can still happen. Bad data can go over a good protocol.

A protocol weakness could allow for known plain text or compression analysis type attacks (e.g., [CRIME](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/beast-vs-crime-attack/)). When you are attacking a encryption protocol, you are generally trying to mess with the confidentiality by finding a way to guess keys, decrypt, influence key choice, etc.

It sounds like perhaps your are asking if a protocol could have rules such that good data is modified and then interpreted on the other end such that it triggers an exploit. Theoretically based on the options and processing of protocol, that may be possible, but in most cases that would still be considered  flaw in the sever or client.

Comment: You can search for CVEs specific to your client software on google or some site like: http://www.itsecdb.com/oval/definitions/product-12081/0/Openssh-Openssh.html?class=5

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but my question was more about the SSH protocol itself.  If there is no error/oversight on the SSH client could a compromised server execute arbitrary code or gain access to any directories on the client?

Comment: @nomizzz the protocol? I'm not sure how you exploit a protocol. You exploit code...

Comment: @schroeder you can exploit a protocol/algorithm if its definition leaves an oversight, omission, or even an overly open-ended feature when they prescribe the standard. So the exploit isn't geared toward a "flaw" in a particular piece of implementation code, it rather exploits the theory/standard behind it. For example, the original DES standard can be cracked not due to a code/implementation oversight, but the standard (protocol) itself specifies too small of a key and uses cryptographically insecure algorithms.

Comment: @nomizz You could exploit the protocol, but why not just abuse it? I would recommend editing your question if you want to focus on protocol, since you asked about a specific client and talked about a compromised server. A protocol flaw could result in a DoS, but would more likely be used to defeat confidentiality. The payload would have to be the data, not the protocol itself.